# Sharing backend and frontend input validation or module

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, validation

I want to share input validation because:

- User experience in frontend, instantly tells the user if the input is good/wrong
- Security concerns in backend, even if the user bypass the frontend javascript, a user cannot mess with the RESTful API
- Also javascript in frontend is always conditional to the browser interpreting it and cannot be trusted

What is the best way to share input validation in a full javascript web app (frontend: react, backend: nodejs)?

The solution I am thinking of is creating a validator module with all my javascript validators at the root of my codebase:

- If on localhost, both environments use this module to validate input.
- If in production/preprod, my deployment script copy the module in both frontend and backend before deploying.
- Import code would look like this each time I try to validate an input: `const validator = process.env.ENV === 'local' ? require('../../validator') : require('/validator')`

Is there any other widely accepted method to do this (I guess it is a very common problem but I didn't find similar issues)? If not, is my method correct?

Comment: You are correct in wanting to validate in both front end and back end. How you do that is up to you, but your solution could work if your validation is a module of some sort. I would argue you need different validation for FE vs BE, as you have different goals. FE - user journey, not allowing input that will fail / error. BE - not allowing data will break / harm system, and FE+BE - ensuring data is 'valid' (i.e. phone number is a phone number, etc.).

Comment: But sharing the code would be extremely useful. A user with an up to date browser not trying to bypass the frontend validation would always get his errors before submitting its input. So I would at least need a backend validation that is as stringent as my frontend, and then I can add some custom validation in backend. Sharing it would save a lot of time, avoid duplicate code, and synchronise backend and frontend teams when they change inputs validation. Thanks for raising the interesting difference between valid and harmful data

Comment: Presumably in a shared module you'd have rules marked for "back-end-only", and the rule would never get exposed to front-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Takeaways from answers and implementation:**

- Implementation works and is a good way to take advantage of a fullstack javascript app
- It creates some complexity and you need to be careful not to implement libraries/javascript methods that won't behave the same between two very different environments (on a client browser and on a nodejs backend). Thus I won't be using any third-party library and only vanilla javascript in my validator (example: don't use the `export` keyword in my validator but use `module.exports = {}`, because ES6 `export` won't work in nodejs)
- If you want to avoid bugs in production, you shall always deploy both in frontend and backend each time you modify your `validator` module and test in both environments (I added a script that runs before deploying and check for diff between the 2 modules)
- Because it makes me gain so much time, I now also share other piece of functional programming in my app
- Realised that this way of using your own module is just a lot like using an npm module both in frontend and backend (it is just less cumbersome than having to publish it on npm registry if you think it will be useless for the community)

Comment: I was wondering, how did you implement this? I am thinking about doing something similar, but I am not sure how to start...
Did you create a new package imported by both FE & BE like `import 'my-shared-module'`? Or do you simply refer to the folder which is outside both projects?

Comment: From what I remember I did conditional importing depending on my environment. If I in local I refered to a folder outside the project. If in prod I refered directly to the file (they were both copied by a script before deployment). Don't know if it is clear I can precise.

Comment: I think there are better ways to do it for sure

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice to use validations as a module but you should consider what would happen if for some reason you will have/want to change the back-end tech to something that is not Javascript like node.

In case you are going to implement it - you will have a dependency of the client and server on this module and you'll have to maintain different versions of this module or deploy client code and server code any time you have a validation change - which leads to some complexity you should take into your consideration as well .

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would make simple validations on front-end and more complex validation on the backend

For example: validate if e-mail with regex on front-end, send a simple mail to confirm existence of that email

Comment: More complex often means that you can at least build upon the simple one. So that's why I would like to duplicate the frontend validation with backend. It does not imply that I am not doing custom validation in backend. The resulting code in backend may not be optimised following this method, but I am more looking for extra safety + frontend/backend synchronisation than extra performance here.